# Analogous of induction on a $\sigma-$algebra generated by a family of sets $\mathcal F$

Tags: measure-theory

On Tao's Measure theory there is this:

$\mathbf {\text{Remark} 1.4.15.} $ From the definitions, it is clear that we have the following principle, somewhat analogous to the principle of mathematical induction: if $\mathcal F$ is a family of sets in $X$, and $P(E)$ is a
property of sets $E \subset X$ which obeys the following axioms:

1. $P(\varnothing)$ is true
2. $P(E)$ is true for all $E \in \mathcal F$
3. If $P(E)$ is true for some $E \subset X$ then $P(X\setminus E)$ is true also
4. If $E_1, E_2, \ldots \subset X$ are such that $P(E_n)$ is true for all $n$, then $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}E_n$ is true also.

Then one can conclude that $P(E)$ is true for all $E \in \langle \mathcal F \rangle$. Indeed,
the set of all $E$ for which $P(E)$ holds is a $\sigma-$algebra that contains $\mathcal F$,
whence the claim.

Here $\langle \mathcal F \rangle$ is the coarsest $\sigma-$algebra which contains $\mathcal F$.

Honestly I can't see how this is obvious. I thought it would be proved through the explicit construction of this algebra, but that is done in the next page.
Is there something easier I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically we are using the fact that a sigma algebra generated by a family of sets $F$ is the smallest possible sigma algebra that contains $F$.  Let $A=\{B \in F : P(B)\}$.  Conditions 1-4 tell us that $A$ is a sigma algebra that contains $F$.  Hence it must contain the smallest sigma algebra, namely $\sigma(F)$.  Hence for any $B \in  \sigma(F)$ we have $P(B)$.